# angularjs: show container only after $resource.query result returned

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I started using angularjs in my app and I encountered a problem when I load server results dynamically. 
I have a resource:

```
var GroupingTagMachines = $resource('/grouping_tags/:grouping_tag_id/machines', { format: 'json' }, 
                                      { 
                                        query: { method: 'get', cache: true, isArray: true }
                                      });
```

And I use it when a link is cliked:

HTML:

```
<a href data-ng-click="show($event, tag)">click me</a>
```

JS:

```
scope.show = function($event, tag) {
    var clicked_link = $($event.currentTarget);
    var tags_list = clicked_link.parent(".grouping-tag").find(".tag-machines");

    if(tags_list.is(":visible")) {
      tags_list.slideUp();
    } else {
      GroupingTagMachines.query({ "grouping_tag_id": tag.id }, function(tag_machines) {
        tag.machines = tag_machines;
        console.log(tag.machines.length + " machines returned");
        tags_list.slideDown();
      });
    }
  };
```

Now when the link is clicked, the container div is being shown (with the slide down animation) and then the results appear inside. 
As you can see, I make the container visible in my resource callback method, so the server is supposed to response before.

The desired behavior is the results to show up only after the container becomes visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show the code for `tags_list.slideDown()`. It looks like you're doing DOM manipulation in the controller, which is not a good idea in Angular. I'm guessing that the DOM manipulation happens outside of Angular's digest cycle causing this problem ... but just a hunch until we can see what that `slideDown()` function is doing (if appropriate, show the HTML for the container too).

Comment: slideDown() is jQuery function... http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is related to using jQuery and Angular together. In short, Angular uses "digest cycles" to update the screen. So when jQuery does it's thing Angular doesn't know about it.

The `slideDown()` function takes two arguments. The first is a duration of the slide animation, the second is a callback that can be executed when the animation completes.

Try using that callback to update the screen w/the results from the server:

```
// 400 ms seems to be the default
tags_list.slideDown(400, function() {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
      tag.machines = tag_machines;
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** If you get a "digest is already in progress" error message, just take out the call to `$scope.$apply()` and assign server result to `tag.machines`.

**EDIT #2:** Looks like I got the interaction wrong b/c I was expanding the container, then adding the items. To add the items first and then expand, you can use the `$timeout` service:

```
tag.machines = tag_machines;
// don't forget to inject $timeout into your controller
$timeout(function() { tags_list.slideDown() });
```

This should delay the slide effect till the next digest cycle. However, I'm thinking that by merely adding the items to the container, the container will grow and then eventually play the slide down effect. You might need some extra CSS to get it right.

Also, if you ditch jQuery and do it all in Angular these problems start to go away. I've had fun using the [Angular Motion](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-motion) project.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if I get you right, I'm afraid it's the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve. If I go with your suggestion, the container will be populated AFTER the slide. I want it to be populated first and then the slide to take action.

Comment: @benams Got it, my bad. So instead of using `$scope.$apply()` to set the result from the server, you can use `$timeout` to trigger the slide down effect on the next digest cycle. I'll add this to my answer...

Comment: It works. Thanks.
I really hate using timeouts for achieving a nice UI, it feels like a patch, but I guess I don't have many other choices here...